# Ajax call to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm working in a project which I have to use several inputs which have to be completed by the client inserting a number. If the number is equal or more than 6, 'aprobada' should appear in the input text, else 'reprobada'. Is it possible to pass variables from php to jquery?

All comments and feedback are welcome :)

Thank you!

```
CODE JQUERY ,HTML


<script src="jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script>
function submitForm() {
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'formtronco.php', data:$('#troncocomun').serialize(),
success:    function(response) {


$('#troncocomun').find('#aqui').html(response);  /*here would be this variable  
'$acreditacion[0]' from php to respond in '#aqui'*/   
$('#troncocomun').find('#alla').html(response); /*here would be this variable    
'$acreditacion[1]' from php to respond in '#alla'*/ 
}});


return false;
}

</script>



....
<!-- PRIMER SEMESTRE -->
<div class="nivel">NIVEL I</div>
<form class="creditos" onsubmit="return submitForm();"  name="troncocomun" 
id="troncocomun" method="post" >
<div class="semestre1" >
<table >
<tr>
<td >
UNIDADES DE APRENDIZAJE
</td>
<td>
VALOR EN CRÉDITOS
</td>
<td >
CALIFICACIÓN 
</td>
<td >
ACREDITACIÓN
</td>
<td >
CARGA ACADÉMICA
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  nowrap id="materia">
ALGEBRA
</td>
<td>
5.62
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="1" name="1" size="3px">

</td>
<td id="aqui" name="aqui">

</td>
<td>
Row 1
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td nowrap id="materia">
COMPUTACION BASICA I
</td>
<td>
4.5
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="2" name="2" size="3px">
</td>
<td id="alla" name="alla">   
</td>
<td >
Row 2
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Procesar" />          

</form>



CODE PHP:


<?php

if(isset($_POST['1'])) 
{
$acreditacion=array($_POST['1'],$_POST['2']);
if ($acreditacion[0] >=6 ) {
echo "Aprobada";}
else{
echo "Reprobada";
}

if ($acreditacion[1] >=6 ) {
echo "Aprobada";}
else{
echo "Reprobada";
}


} 
?>
```

Comment: A question with code that is not properly indented sends the following message: "I don't care if anyone can read my code"

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you're not passing a variable from PHP to JS, you're making an AJAX call to a PHP file asking for JSON data.

```
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url: 'formtronco.php', 
        data:$('#troncocomun').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            // If you're querying by ID, no need to search within another node
            $('#aqui').html(data.val1);
            $('#alla').html(data.val2); 
        }
    });
});
```

And in `formtronco.php`

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array(
    'val1' => 'Some string',
    'val2' => 'Another string'
));
?>
```

To pass a variable to JS from PHP (what you actually asked) do the following

```
<script>
var errorMessage = <?php echo json_encode($errorMsgPhpVar); ?>;
alert(errorMessage);
</script>
```

`json_encode` will make it work even for strings with quotes and embedded new lines, besides working for PHP objects.

Comment: ok,but how can i use this var to this other line , $('#troncocomun').find('#aqui').html(response);

Comment: @EduardoRobles So you're not trying to pass a variable from PHP to JS, you're trying to generate a php script that can be used in an AJAX call.

Comment: ok,i'm new in ajax ,any clue about this ,how can i make the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Not the tidiest thing, really. But this answer your question:

```
<script>
var someVariable = <?php echo $phpVar; ?>;
</script>
```

Assuming `$phpVar = 1`, this'd output:

```
<script>
var someVariable = 1;
</script>
```

Make sure you include this BEFORE other javascript that references this variable.

You shouldn't be doing this though, since it's very untidy - you should't actually be needing to "pass variables" like that.

Comment: The only problem with this is the case where your variable is a string, because it needs to be escaped. Or if it's an object. An easy way to get around this problem is by encoding your data using JSON. In some places, you cannot change your entire architecture to be AJAX based and this technique is necessary. You may also want to avoid an initial AJAX request for some reason

Comment: You can use a json object without recurring to ajax though. Just inline the object, and then extract the value through js.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by inlining the object, but if you see my answer I think we're in agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to create an element that holds your variable when the page loads, for example, make a hidden input field

```
<input class="myVar" type="hidden" value="<?= $phpMyVar ?>">
```

Then using Javascript, you can select that hidden input by the ID and get the value from it.

(this is jquery)

```
var myVal = $('.myVar').val();
```

This way you can access the variable at any time and even place your javascript wherever you want.

Comment: You don't really need a hidden field here, just a variable, according to what the OP posted

Comment: Sure, I'm only suggesting a DOM element that can be accessed at any time and not have to worry about in-line javascript elements or even external javascript to be loaded after the page loads - a hidden input is only an example - which he will have access to at any time.

Comment: And I'm just saying that's much heavier-weight than a variable, it's not any cleaner than adding a variable...

Comment: That's fine - I was just giving another option.  I never said it was a cleaner or better way to do it.